# Is 'Nail(s) Spa' correct?

Tags: idioms, is-it-a-word

I wanted to know if the term “Nail Spa” or “Nails Spa” is correct? I am opening a nail salon and would like to know which one would be correct. I know that Nail salon is correct not nails salon but referring to spa seems different to me and I cannot find an answer online about nail(s) with SPA

Comment: It's also "Shoe Store" .  If however there would be proper name with the word of the good or service in it, generally it is plural.  Harry's Shoes,  Everlasting Nails

Answer (score 1):

"Nail Spa" seems to be fairly common as a description or business name for this type of salon.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's nail spa for the same reason it is nail salon, grocery store, car dealership, book store, pastry shop, etc (instead of groceries store, cars dealership, books store, pastries shop).

Answer (score 0):

When a noun is used as an adjective, it is (almost) always used in the singular, including words that don't otherwise see singular usage:

> trousers, trouser press
>
> pyjamas, pyjama top

"Nail" is no exception:

> nail, nails, nail spa